# MySqlHelper.ExecuteDataset returning wrong values on field Tinyint(1)

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a Database with a table who has a field Tinyint(1) but isn't a boolean it's simply a number from 0 to 9.

When I extract data from this table using:

```
Dim ds As DataSet = MySqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(CnStr, SqlStr)
```

the resulted "dataset.table(0)" doesn't contain the field value.

The returned value is a boolean. So I get only "TRUE" for every value of the field and when I insert data into another table, the inserted value is 0.

I solved changing field type from Tinyint(1) to Tinyint(2) but I'd like to know if someone else faced the same problem and if is there a better way to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the connection string

```
TreatTinyAsBoolean=false
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connection-options.html

Comment: Thanks for useful link

Comment: Glad to help, another trick if you only need to store positive numbers in the Tinyint field is to define it as "unsigned" & then it returns a byte value 0-255 rather than true/false.